# Where is the installed applications are stored in android 9?

Tags: adb, installation, apk

I have seen few examples in the internet but couldn't find the right answer about my phone. In my phone how does a file manager app finds the ***base.apk*** of an installed app? and how can I find them using ***adb*** or terminal apps?

Comment: Any app can query the list of installed packages and their apk file paths (with some restrictions added in recent Android releases). Run: `adb shell pm list package -f`

Comment: how do they start adb server in the first place .and they have to get the APK file. What's the adb command for that.im curious.

Comment: Apps use Android APIs, not ADB. See [`getInstalledApplications`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(int)) and [`sourceDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#sourceDir).

Comment: I have root and non rooted Device. In rooted phone (android 7) I just can look up the internal directories and that I did ***/data/app/***. But the same folder didn't work on my non rooted phone (android 9). And can I get the source directory printed out using a terminal like termux? The APK files should be readable.

Comment: there is at least one app in google play (Dev Tools) that will show you exact install path of apps

Comment: @alecxs that's what I was looking for. In my Android 7 (rooted) the path is ***data/app/com.package.name-1/base.apk*** and in non rooted instead of 1 it's some kind of base64 string.

Comment: that's the newer android version, I believe since 8 or 9. anyway /data/app/pkgname-\*/base.apk would do it

Comment: Yep any idea what that * could be?

Comment: IMHO [SecureRandom()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958947/base64-apk-path#comment115186029_50895776) was added to make more unique dirname for each version of app